# Is it possible to avoid creating java.sql.Date Object in For Loop

Tags: java

While Inserting Date into mysql , i have the following code

```
DateFormat format_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-mm-dd");
for (Stocker s : symbol_set) {
    insert_stmt.setString(1, s.getName());
    insert_stmt.setDouble(2, s.getPrice());
    Date d = format_date.parse(s.getCurr_day());
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime()); 
    insert_stmt.setDate(3, sqlDate);
    insert_stmt.setString(4, s.getVolume());
    insert_stmt.setDouble(5, s.getGainloss());
    insert_stmt.addBatch();
}
insert_stmt.executeBatch();
```

Could you please let me know Is it possible to avoid  creating java.sql.Date Object in For Loop or is this normal behaviour and cannot be skipped ??

Comment: Why don't you create the variable outside the loop, then just call the variable inside the loop, assigning it the new date each iteration?

Comment: @EvanBechtol: That wouldn't have any performance benefits. Just declaring a variable in the loop has no cost.

Comment: So basically you're asking if there's a way to parse `s.getCurr_day()` to `java.sql.Date` directly. Sounds like a premature micro-optimization to me, FWIW.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is true, but he isn't asking about performance benefits. He is asking if it is "normal behavior and cannot be skipped"

Comment: You can not avoid this because you need separate references for all row.

Comment: @EvanBechtol: The OP isn't asking about avoiding declaring the variable, either - they're asking about avoiding creating the *object*. The only reason I can think they'd want to do that is for performance. I agree the question could be clearer, but I don't think your suggestion is relevant to the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah I see what you are saying now. thanks for clearing the question up

Comment: If you would have `yyyy-mm-dd` a `setString(s.getCurr_dat())` might probably work as that is ISO date format. I doubt that you can prefix with `"20" + ...`. But the costs are not that high.

Comment: Your format string should probably be `yy-MM-dd` (assuming you want the month).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion created by me , yes my question is related to performance only .

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the implementation of `PreparedStatement.setDate()` and `addBatch()`.

*If* those methods clone all the relevant data appropriately, you could create a single instance of `java.sql.Date` outside the loop, then call `setTime` on that instance before calling `setDate`.

However, that behaviour isn't documented, so I personally wouldn't want to rely on it. (This is one annoyance of mutable types - you can't easily guarantee the effect of mutation and reuse.) Basically it *is* normal behaviour unless you're really comfortable relying on a specific implementation detail - and that sounds like a really bad idea to me.

The good news is that each instance is going to be small... I'd be very surprised if this were *really* a performance issue compared with the fact that you're talking to a database.